# How to use an OCX from a web-browser context in VB6 instead?

Tags: vb6, ocx

I'm using an EDIMAX IP Cam (IC-1520DP) which has a browser based administration. When you first login, it requires installation of an OCX (IPCamPluginMJPEG.ocx). This OCX then operates within the browser effectively as part of the web page.

Now I want to use this OCX to display the camera images on a form in VB6. I can add a reference to the OCX but **it is unclear how to initialize or use it**. In the browser web page I can see that its asking for some parameters that are being passed to it by the `PARAM` HTML tag.

Obviously I can't use the `PARAM` tag in VB6, so is there any other way I can pass the parameters?

---

<sub>(Or do you have better ways to display the live camera feed on a form in VB6?
The camera also has this CGI command that returns One multipart JPEG video stream but I totally don't have any idea how to use it.)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple: Take the name attribute of the param tag and set the same property of the ActiveX control with the value of the value attribute. Like this:

```
Sub Form_Load()
    MyControl.Param = Value
    ...
End Sub
```

Comment: +1. The attributes may also appear in the VB form designer properties window.